# How to mute specific processes in Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, alsa

Simple question. I'm looking for a way (command or otherwise) to mute the sound from specific applications.  For instance, I could mute a particularly noisy game I'm playing while still listening to RhythmBox. Is it possible at all?

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10, with alsa sound driver.

Comment: In Simple way, Check the game settings to mute the sound :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the **Sound Preferences** window (System -> Preferences -> Sound)

Click the tab all the way to the right that says **Applications**

This tab lists programs using the ALSA plugin and allows you to mute individual programs

edited for clarity, original below:

Try right clicking on the speaker icon that is in the top right corner by default and go to sound preferences. Click the tab all the way to the right that says Applications and it will give a list of all programs using the ALSA plugin and allows you to have separate volume control over each of them as well as muting individual programs. Hope thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Kind of a nitpick, but both your answer and the question mention alsa, when this information does not apply to alsa, but only to pulseaudio and its alsa emulation.